# PHP script ,MySQL

Tags: c#, php, sql

I'm writing a php script. I need client-server communication with the database.

I want to count how many ID's there are in DTB, so I wrote this:

```
$id= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'], $db); 
$query = "SELECT COUNT( id ) FROM scores WHERE id = $id;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

My php skills is really low... I send in parameter id to php script, and count ID's in table. But i don't know how to return a result (INTEGER) from php to my C#;

My C# script

```
IEnumerator IDExist(int id) // Ci ID EXISTUJE
{
    string post_url = getid + "&id=" + id;

    WWW hs_get = new WWW(post_url);
    yield return hs_get;

    if (hs_get.error != null)
    {

    }
    Debug.Log(hs_get.text);
}
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Please dont use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated and are being removed from PHP. Use mysqli_* instead.

Comment: Pls , can you tell me how ? i am low in php ,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code from

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT( id ) FROM scores WHERE id = $id;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT( id ) as `total_ids` FROM scores WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

after that you need

```
 $count = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $count['total_ids']; // it will give you result
```

when writing a query there is no need to use a `;`  inside a string unless your writing multiple queries. which btw are not supported by normal mysql.

other than that `mysql_*` is no longer supported please check this [**link**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for `mysqli_*` database driver